# How to sort and edit a map?

Tags: java

I have a Payment object which have date and amount fields.

```
List<Payment>
```

I need to loop through the Payment and will put date & amount in a map(date is key here).
Lets say I have some data in Payment object for date and amount fields as follows.

```
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 10
date: 16-01-2018, amount: 30
date: 11-01-2018, amount: 50
date: 19-01-2012, amount: 30
date: 12-01-2017, amount: 70
```

Now I will get this data in sequence and I want to put this data into a map in sorting order (on date) like this:

```
1st entry in map:
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 10

2nd entry:
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 10
date: 16-01-2018, amount: 40(here adding earlier date amount which is 10 for 14-01-2018 )

3rd entry:
date: 11-01-2018, amount: 50
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 60 (in 2nd entry for this date amount was 10, but since date 11-01-2018 having amount 50 then i adding 50 to 10)
date: 16-01-2018, amount: 90(same here, as in 2nd entry for this date amount was 40 but need to add 50 of 11-01-2018 as this date is before)

4th entry:
date: 19-01-2012, amount: 30 (since this date will come first i need to add this amount to all later date's amount)
date: 11-01-2018, amount: 80
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 90
date: 16-01-2018, amount: 120

5th entry:
date: 19-01-2012, amount: 30
date: 12-01-2017, amount: 70(this date will come at 2nd place because of sorting, its amount is 70 but it's earlier date 9-01-2012 has amount 30, so need to add that amount and 12-01-2017 amount will become 100, and later date's amount will increase by 70)
date: 11-01-2018, amount: 150
date: 14-01-2018, amount: 160
date: 16-01-2018, amount: 190
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Where is the code!?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a sorted map, such as a `TreeMap`, and aggregate in to it:

```
TreeMap<Date, Double> sum = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Payment::getDate,
                                       TreeMap::new, 
                                       Collectors.summingDouble(Payment::getAmount)
                                      )
                );
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. I don't think it really helps to give away the answer.